# eclipse luna (pydev 3.8) doesn't show admin template base.html

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I'm REALLY confused, weird, but fact, my eclipse luna with pydev 3.8 version (python 2.7) doesn't show any templates from django.contrib.admin app. 
I mean, if I try to open django.contrib.admin.templates.admin.base.html in eclipse the only what I see is ERROR.

[image]

Files are in place! I can open/edit admin files with an editor (not eclipse)

I can open/edit any other content. but admin.template!

Also, if I try to debug admin app, then debugger breaks on base.html:16 while I have NOT set any break points there. Just like on the screenshot:

[image]

Very frustrating and very odd. Same system, but older virtenv (with prev version of django and eclipse) everything works as it supposed to.

any ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ok... after few days of meditation I figured out that I had 2 problems.
the 'ERROR' i.s.o. nice html template page is caused by a bug in Django Editor (eclipse plugin http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/)

**solution**: remove buggy software and try to contact the owner of the editor (editor is convenient!)

the other odd behaviour - debug breaks by its own will (no breakpoints set!) somewhere inside a template page - is a bug of pydev. I have no clue where.

**solution**: set TEMPLATE_DEBUG to False and try to contact PyDev developers.

thanks, this question can be closed.